# Write data from Hadoop MapReduce job into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop

I've been parsing log files using MapReduce, but it always outputs a text file named "part-00000" to store my results, and I have to then import `part--00000` into mysql manually.

**Is there an easy way to store MapReduce results directly in MySQL?** For example, how might I store the results of the classic "Word Count" MapReduce program in MySQL directly?

I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1, and the `mapred` libraries (i.e. `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*` instead of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*`, and the two are not compatible as far as I'm aware.) I don't have access to Sqoop.

Comment: Can you show us some code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using DBOutputFormat, we can write MapReduce output to direct databases.

Here is some [example](https://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/tag/dboutputformat/), go through this.

Personally i suggest [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html) for Data imports (from DB to HDFS) and exports (From hdfs to DB).